# record inserts, but doesn't update mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue trying to update my database. I'm able to insert if it doesn't exist, but it doesn't update the record if exists. I think is not finding the current values of the table. Any ideas?

```
<?php
function add_log($input_output, $l_sales, $l_enroll, $l_offers)
{
    global $database;
    $date           =   date('m-d-Y');
    $l_sales        =   safety_filter($l_sales);
    $l_enroll       =   safety_filter($l_enroll);
    $l_offers       =   safety_filter($l_offers);
    $cusersup       =   get_the_current_user('u_manager');
    $cuseropm       =   get_the_current_user('u_opsmanager');
    $cuserid        =   get_the_current_user('id');
    $cuser          =   get_the_current_user('user_name');

    if($input_output == 'input')
    {
        $query_call = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM $database->log WHERE l_date='$date' AND l_user_name='$cuser'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($query_call) > 0)
        {
            while($list_calls = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_call))
            {
                $old_calls = $list_calls['l_calls'];
                $old_sales = $list_calls['l_sales'];
                $old_enroll = $list_calls['l_enroll'];
                $old_offers = $list_calls['l_offers'];
            }


            $update = mysql_query("UPDATE $database->log SET
            l_call=[$old_calls] + [1],
            l_sales=[$old_sales] + [$l_sales],
            l_enroll=[$old_enroll] + [$l_enroll],
            l_offers=[$old_offers] + [$l_offers]
            WHERE l_date='$date' AND l
            _user_name='$cuser'");
            if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){return true;  }
            else { if($update == true){ return true; } else { return false; } }
        }
        else
        {

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO $database->log (l_date, l_user_name, l_calls, l_sales, l_enroll, l_offers) VALUES ('$date', '$cuser', '1', '$l_sales', '$l_enroll', '$l_offers')");
            if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){return true; }
            else{ return false; }
        }   
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: I think you also have a race condition here. Why not use "l_sales = l_sales + $l_sales" (changing to use prepared statements, of course)?

Comment: But I expect the problem you're having is because you're trying to reference columns read back when all that you actually asked for is "1" and/or because you're trying to update `l_call` when the column name appears to be `l_calls`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are selecting 1 ("SELECT 1 FROM..."), so you are never getting any of the values from the table (just the number "1").  This tells you something is there, but doesn't actually return any values.

Try selecting all fields ("SELECT * FROM..."), or at least list the fields you need to do the update.